# Tooltip doesnt show to Child window Element

Tags: javascript, html

I have one div with large content in Parent window. I have to display this content into the new Child window. I am sending the div containing the data and this div is created in Parent Window. I am just injecting this div to child window and I am able to display its content.

Only the problem is when I hover on to the button of this child window, the tooltip displays onto Parent Window but it should be in Child window.

I tried getting the button element by window.document.getElementById() but it gives me null... So I think its something DOM Element problem but not able to figure out.

It might be the case that as I am sending a div to this child window, the element objects are not available to child window.

below is the code which i just explained above :

Note : form3YBP : Div which I am getting from one of the method, injecting and displaying into window.

```
pdfWindow = window.open('','Download Plan','width=1280,height=900');
var popUpDoc = pdfWindow.document;


DownloadElement = pdfWindow.document.getElementById("#btnDownload"); //giving null
if(isChrome){

   var tooltipForChrome = new Tooltip({
    target: DownloadElement,               
    position : DownloadElement,
    events : {
        'onShow' : function(){
            console.log("OnShow this : "+DownloadElement);
            console.log(this);
        }
    },
    body: 'You may use the <b>Save as PDF</b> printer destination to create a local copy of your document!'
    });
}
form3YBP.inject(pdfWindow.document.body);
pdfWindow.document.close();
```

Does anyone have idea about this?

Any suggestion would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `document.getElementById` doesn't use CSS selector syntax, so you shouldn't prepend the ID with a "#". It should read `pdfWindow.document.getElementById("btnDownload")`

Comment: yes, I have changed it and now it gives me the buttonElement. Still tooltip shows in parent window not in child window(popup). I also tried window.focus() but no change. I dont have any error.

Comment: Try posting a SO snippet, fiddle, or jsbin that replicates this issue.